# Como usar where en data set para filtrar resultado

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Tengo un data set que es llamado a partir de un servicio web. Lo que intento hacer es llamar este servicio web filtrando el tipo de proyecto que deseo obtener.

Esto quiere decir que no quiero llamar los proyectos que tengan como DefinitionType "Survey".

He intentado de hacerlo de varias veces pero no me resulta, alguna sugerencia?

Aqui esta la estructura del data set:

```
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="ProjectID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Language" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Subcategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="CategoryID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="SubcategoryID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Private" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Archived" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="BaseLanguage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Confidential" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="DefinitionType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Aquí esta mi código el cual trato de efectuar el filtro de donde pongo el where me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> *(Possible unintended reference comparaison; to get a value compararison, cast the left hand side to type 'string').*

Lo cual he tratado de hacer, pero sin resultado:

```
string projectId = proj.ProjectID.ToString();
var projectType = client.GetProjectDetails(ref apiKey, ref message, languages);
var type = projectType.Tables["Table"].Select("ProjectId = '" + projectId + "'")
    .Select(r => r["DefinitionType"])
    .Where(s => s != "survey") //aqui me aparece el mensaje mencionado.
    .Select(s => s.ToString())       
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Si ya ha aplicado esta línea: `Select("ProjectId = '" + projectId + "'")` ¿porqué aplica nuevamente otro filtro?; intente primero obtener los resultados del primer filtro "el primer Select", si los datos filtrados son los esperados, agregue los demás filtros. Ej: `.Select("ProjectId = '" + projectId + "' AND DefinitionType = 'Definición 1'");`

Comment: el primero filtro es para que el projectID de la llamada del servicio web GetProjectDetails sea el mismo projectID que tengo desde otra llamada de otro servicio web para asi evitar duplicado en el resultado es por eso que necesito el primer filtro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar un dataset con linq requieres que este sea `AsEnumerable()`

[Ejemplos de sintaxis de expresiones de consulta: proyección (LINQ to DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb386943%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DataTable dt = projectType.Tables["Table"];

var type = dt.AsEnumerable().
            .Where(s => s.Field<string>("DefinitionType") != "survey") 
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque defines tanto `Select()`

Comment: Tenia muchos select() hice el cambio que me sugeriste en el where y me resulto lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias